Verses 5-42-45 from Mahabharata related to Pramada
I am looking for the exact Sanskrit verse from Mahabharata related to Pramada.
as per wikipedia Pramada is defined as below
Pramada understood as wrong perception of the nature of the world amounts to death (Mahabharata 5.42-45).

I have found the English explanation of the same in English Mahabharata book on wisdomlib but have hard time locating the original Sanskrit verse.
If anyone can help on this, it would be really helpful.

Mahabharata, Book 5: Udyoga Prava, Chapter 42


वैशंपायन उवाच ।
ततो राजा धृतराष्ट्रो मनीषी संपूज्य वाक्यं विदुरेरितं तत् ।
सनत्सुजातं रहिते महात्मा पप्रच्छ बुद्धिं परमां बुभूषन् ॥ १ ॥
"Vaisampayana said, 'Then the illustrious and wise king Dhritarashtra, having applauded the words spoken by Vidura, questioned Sanat-sujata in secret, desirous of obtaining the highest of all knowledge.




धृतराष्ट्र उवाच ।
सनत्सुजात यदीदं शृणोमि मृत्युर्हि नास्तीति तवोपदेशम् ।
देवासुरा ह्याचरन्ब्रह्मचर्यममृत्यवे तत्कतरन्नु सत्यम् ॥ २ ॥
And the king questioned the Rishi saying, 'O Sanat-sujata, I hear that you are of the opinion that there is no Death. Again it is said that the gods and the Asuras, practise ascetic austerities in order to avoid death. Of these two opinions, then, which is true?'




सनत्सुजात उवाच ।
अमृत्युः कर्मणा केचिन्मृत्युर्नास्तीति चापरे ।
शृणु मे ब्रुवतो राजन्यथैतन्मा विशङ्किथाः ॥ ३ ॥
Sanat-sujata said, ’some say, death is avertable by particular acts; others' opinion there is no death; you have asked me which of these is true. Listen to me, O king, as I discourse to you on this, so that your doubts may be removed.




उभे सत्ये क्षत्रियाद्यप्रवृत्ते मोहो मृत्युः संमतो यः कवीनाम् ।
प्रमादं वै मृत्युमहं ब्रवीमि सदाप्रमादममृतत्वं ब्रवीमि ॥ ४ ॥
Know, O Kshatriya, that both of these are true. The learned are of opinion that death results from ignorance. I say that ignorance is Death, and so the absence of ignorance (Knowledge) is immortality.



Sanskrit Shloka Source: Mahabharata [Sanskrit], Book 5, Chapter 42
Hindi Translation Source: Mahabharata Volume 3, Hindi Translation, Gita Press
English Translation Source: Mahabharata (English), Book 5, Section XLII

In the Mahabharata, Book 5, Chapter 42, verses 45-46 discuss the dangers of pramada (carelessness or negligence) in various contexts, highlighting its destructive potential. The verses caution against neglect in duties and the consequences of failing to maintain vigilance, emphasizing the importance of awareness and responsibility in upholding dharma
Sanskrit: प्रमादं शुश्रूषास्तेषां विघ्नान्प्राप्नुयुरज्ञयः।Transliteration: pramādaṁ śuśrūṣāsteṣāṁ vighnān prāpnuyurajñayaḥ।Translation: "Neglect is verily said to be the greatest impediment that overtakes those that are unwise."This verse underscores the consequences of negligence (pramada) for those lacking wisdom and vigilance.
